# CPU Time vs Buffer gets oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-performance, sql-tuning

in order to improve performance of a query, which one to choose?

CPU_time high and buffer_gets low

or

CPU_time low and buffer_gets high

Answer (score 1):

`buffer_gets` represents the number of times Oracle has to read a block. The reads are satisfied from memory (cache) or disk.

Since disk I/O is far more expensive than CPU time, generally you should concentrate on reducing `buffer_gets` as much as possible.

`CPU_time` "high" in relation to *other queries* may be insignificant if it represents a small percentage of the *total* CPU capacity. If it does represent a large percentage, then it needs to be looked into as well.

Comment: So if I reduce the buffer size, will there be improvement in sql performance?

Comment: Don't reduce **buffer size**, adjust the SQL query such that **buffer_gets** is reduced.